# Can't assign to first element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, assign

For some reason I can't assign a random number to this first element in an int array I created.  The problem is at the 7th line: `coord[0] = (int) (math.random() * numRows + 1);`   I posted the error below.

```
public class Ship {

int shipLength = 3;
int numRows = 5;

int[] coord = new int[shipLength];
coord[0] = (int) (math.random() * numRows + 1);

    for (int i=1;i<shipLength;i++){
        coord[i] = coord[i-1] + 1;
    }
    public setCoord(cell){
        coord[cell] = null;
    }

    public int[] getCoord(cell){
    return coord[[cell];
    }
} //class




C:\java\Battleship>javac Ship.java
Ship.java:7: ']' expected
coord[0] = (int) (math.random() * numRows + 1);
      ^
Ship.java:7: ';' expected
coord[0] = (int) (math.random() * numRows + 1);
       ^
Ship.java:7: illegal start of type
coord[0] = (int) (math.random() * numRows + 1);
         ^
Ship.java:7: <identifier> expected
coord[0] = (int) (math.random() * numRows + 1);
          ^
```

Comment: When do you think that code should be executed? What are class bodies for?

Comment: Where is the method??Your structure of the code is wrong

Comment: I recommend you see a basic java tutorial.
This is a good tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation juan, I'm actually doing a tutorial now but the pace was a little slow so I tried going a bit beyond what I was asked in the exercise for my own sanity and entertainment.

Comment: @Sotirios it's for a battleship game program.  This is the class that creates a battleship at random coordinates in a virtual plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular line that you're code is failing on is a valid line of code, but it needs to be within a method or a constructor for your class.

For example:

```
public class Ship {

    int shipLength = 3;
    int numRows = 5;

    int[] coord = new int[shipLength];
    public Ship() {
        coord[0] = (int) (Math.random() * numRows + 1);
        for (int i=1;i<shipLength;i++){
            coord[i] = coord[i-1] + 1;
        }
    }
    public void setCoord(int cell, int value){
        coord[cell] = value;
    }

    public int getCoord(int cell){
        return coord[cell];
    }
}
```

Comment: It still won't compile-- it's littered with errors. The `setCoord` method has no return type, the `getCoord` method should return an int, and it has one too many `[`

Comment: @user184994 sorry, I made an update, my first iteration was just putting stuff in a constructor.

Comment: Still need to change the return type of `getCoord`. The `coord` variable is an int array, so `coord[cell]` will return an int :)

Comment: @user184994, yea; was doing corrections by eye as my IDE hadn't loaded yet.

Comment: ah okay so a constructor is necessary when you do anything beyond assigning instance variables to literals.  That makes sense.  Thanks for the help man.

Comment: @user184994 - yah this was my first pass at writing code after psuedocode... so more errors were pretty much inevitable... but this error was totally confusing to me so I felt the need for help.

Comment: @zoogleflatt, just to be clear it doesn't have to be a constructor, it could also be a method (this would be helpful for [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and [lazy init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)).

Answer (score 1):

The code you have after `public class Ship {` and before `public setCoord(cell){` is all at the class level, but it's step-by-step code that has to be inside a constructor, method, or instance initializer.

There were several other basic errors as well.

Perhaps:

```
public class Ship {
    int shipLength = 3;
    int numRows = 5;
    int[] coord;

    public Ship() {

        coord = new int[shipLength];
        coord[0] = (int) (Math.random() * numRows + 1);

        for (int i=1;i<shipLength;i++){
            coord[i] = coord[i-1] + 1;
        }
    }

    public void setCoord(int cell){
        coord[cell] = 0;
    }

    public int getCoord(int cell){
        return coord[cell];
    }
} //class
```

Changes:

1. Put *declarations* (and initializers, though I prefer initializers in constructors) at class level.
2. Put *code* in a constructor.
3. Remove the extra `[` in the last method.
4. Add the missing types for various method return values and arguments.
5. Change `math` to `Math`.

The result now compiles. I suggest looking at the changes compared to the original so you can understand the various issues.

Comment: the `getCoord` method should return an int

Comment: @user184994: And that wasn't all, the code was *riddled* with errors.

Comment: Yep :) I just mentioned the same in another comment